# onException.handled(false) - Any use case for this scenario?

Tags: apache-camel

In Apache Camel, in almost all use cases, we will be using `onException(SomeException.class).handled(true).`

Is there any use cases where we need to use `onException(SomeException.class).handled(false)`?

If we use onException(false), the Exception will be returned to the caller, even though you can change the body in the handling code (original route propagation will be stopped). But if you use `handled(false)`, then can we retrieve the Exchange object to get the original message at the caller? You will only get the Exception, right?

Answer (score 3):

Please check http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/What-s-the-Difference-between-handled-false-and-continued-true-and-more-td4302302.html

As you can see there are the following rules provided by Claus Ibsen:

- **handle(true)** = the exception is handled and removed from the exchange + break out routing
- **handled(false)** = the exception is not handled, so it will be stored as an exception on the exchange + break out routing
- **continue(true)** = handled(true) + continue routing

Comment: typo corrected - handled(true) and continued(true)

Comment: The link seems broken. Do you have another way to reach the article?